# series and inequality

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, reference-request

I found this homework in an old paper written

> Let $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$ and $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|x_{i}\right|=1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}=0$
>
> Show that : $\forall i \in [1;n] \quad \left|\dfrac{2}{i}-1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right|\leq 1-\dfrac{1}{n}$
>
> Deduce that : $\left|\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\dfrac{x_i}{i}\right|\leq\dfrac{1}{2}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$

I tried,

we've  $ \forall i \in [1,n],$
\begin{align*}
1&\leq i\leq n \\
\dfrac{1}{n}&\leq \dfrac{1}{i}\leq 1\\
\dfrac{2}{n}&\leq \dfrac{2}{i}\leq 2\\
\dfrac{2}{n}-1&\leq \dfrac{2}{i}-1\leq 1\\
\dfrac{2}{n}-1-\dfrac{1}{n}&\leq \dfrac{2}{i}-1-\dfrac{1}{n}\leq 1-\dfrac{1}{n}\\
\dfrac{1}{n}-1&\leq \dfrac{2}{i}-1-\dfrac{1}{n}\leq 1-\dfrac{1}{n}\\
\end{align*}

Could you help me please!
More if possible someone tell me which book contains this kind of exercise?
any help would be apperciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence of inequalities you got is correct. Just observe that $\left | a \right| \le b \iff -b \le a \le b$. So, what you showed is exactly the first part of the exercise.

So, using the first part and multiplying by $|x_i|$ we have that

$$\left| 2\frac{x_i}{i} - x_i\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\right|\le|x_i|\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Summing in $i$ and using that $\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|=1$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\left| 2\frac{x_i}{i} - x_i\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\right|\le\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Now, using the triangle inequality you can pass the sum inside the absolute value preserving the inequality and then use that $\sum x_i =0$ to get

$$\left|\sum_{i=1}^n 2\frac{x_i}{i} - \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right|=2\left|\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i}{i}\right|\le \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Dividing by two you have the answer!